# Is choosing an interpreter the same thing as choosing a version of python?

Tags: version, interpreter

Newbie programmer here: I have python 2.7 and 3.3 installed on my machine (windows 7).

Is selecting an interpreter the same thing as telling your computer which version of python you want to run?

Suppose I want to run scripts that use python 2.* conventions.  Do I simply choose to use my python 2.7 interpreter and exclude the 3.3 interpreter?

I'm asking if this can be done instead of having to uninstall whatever version of python I want to ignore.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The interpreter interprets the Python code, so the Python 2 interpreter only interprets Python 2 code.

Since both versions provide `python.exe`, you will only be able to use the one that comes earlier in your system PATH variable. To get around that, I just make a copy of the `python.exe` file in the `C:\Python27` folder and name it `python2.exe`. Do the same thing for Python 3, but rename it to `python3.exe`.

Now, you can run `python2 script.py`. Calling just `python` will execute the Python installation that came first in your PATH, so you can rearrange it to have a "default" Python version.

Note that you can have conflicts with your `C:\PythonXX\Scripts` folders, so make sure that you know which Python version is the default one.